# Cannot execute delphi 7

Tags: delphi, compilation, project

I want to compile my project in delphi 7, but it cannot, and it says

> Unable to create process: Access is denied

Can somebody help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: Try checking the permissions on the folder where the exe is created.

Comment: Also check if the application is already running via TaskManager

Comment: Which process cannot be created? Delphi itself, or your app?  Which OS? What path are they both running from?  Is UAC enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most plausible explanation is that your anti virus software is blocking the execution of the Delphi compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Open Delphi 7 with "Run as administrator"

Comment: I whitelisted the entire Delphi directory tree with my virus checker, even turned it off, but only running Delphi as admin helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you did not want to be giving the folders permissions (UAC), simply install directly in the directory **"C:\"** the windows will not make permission checks .

All install in the **"Program File"** or **"Program File ( x86)"** the operational system will grant checks.

Comment: Or rather: Install to a new directory in c:\, e.g. c:\legacy-Programs\Delphi7